# Can I change what path gets rendered when using bower in an yeoman angular app?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bower, yeoman-generator

I am using html5mode in my angular app, but when I run `bower install` with `grunt`, it renders the paths as

`<script src="bower_components/...`

Can I change this to

`<script src="/bower_components/...`?

I've added a `<base href="/">` tag to my `<head/>` section, but when my pages try to load javascript, they are still looking for relative urls.

So for a script at `/bower_components/script.js`, currently rendered as
`<script src="bower_components/script.js"></script>`,

when on `/login`, the page tries to load `/login/bower_components/script.js`

**EDIT**
Following @sharpper's advice, I added the code block below and ended up with this in Gruntfile.js:

```
// Automatically inject Bower components into the app
'bower-install': {
  app: {
    html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
    ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/',
    fileTypes: {
      html: {
        block: /(([\s\t]*)<!--\s*bower:*(\S*)\s*-->)(\n|\r|.)*?(<!--\s*endbower\s*-->)/gi,
        detect: {
          js: /<script.*src=['"](.+)['"]>/gi,
          css: /<link.*href=['"](.+)['"]/gi
        },
        replace: {
          js: '<script src="/{{filePath}}"></script>', // <-- Change this line
          css: '<link rel="/stylesheet" href="{{filePath}}" />'
        }
      },
      yml: {
        block: /(([\s\t]*)#\s*bower:*(\S*)\s*)(\n|\r|.)*?(#\s*endbower\s*)/gi,
        detect: {
          js: /-\s(.+)/gi,
          css: /-\s(.+)/gi
        },
        replace: {
          js: '- {{filePath}}',
          css: '- {{filePath}}'
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

It still compiles correctly, but the files are rendered the same.

Comment: From memory I do not think bower install actually edits any html files. Are you using any other tools with this? You should be able to change it as long as your web server is hosting these files in the base path.

Comment: When I change it, and rerun grunt, it regenerates the bower section and reverts the changes I make.

Comment: Can you post your gruntfile?

Comment: This is my Gruntfile.js https://gist.github.com/scottmeyer/8246250

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, make sure your bower-install at the latest version: v0.8.0 (yeoman is using v0.7.0 currently), then the code below should work:

```
     'bower-install': {
         app: {
            src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
            ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/',
            fileTypes: {
                html: {
                    replace: {
                        js: '<script src="/{{filePath}}"></script>',
                        css: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/{{filePath}}" />'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

If you don't want to update or this method does not work, try this trick:
       Change `ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/',` to `ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>',` , then it should work for your purpose.

Comment: Changing the `ignorePath` param worked and seemed the most simple solution.

Comment: I had hard time figuring out with v1.4.0. 'bower-install' namespace has changed to 'bowerInstall'.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is an issue with another plugin called `bower-install`. You can find the documentation for this plugin at: https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install

Under the hood it using a plugin called wiredep found here: https://github.com/stephenplusplus/wiredep

It looks like you can pass through parameters to wiredep to change the way it inserts into script tags. You can add a fileTypes configuration parameter to your `'bower-install'` config and override the defaults:

```
html: {
  block: /(([\s\t]*)<!--\s*bower:*(\S*)\s*-->)(\n|\r|.)*?(<!--\s*endbower\s*-->)/gi
  detect: {
    js: /<script.*src=['"](.+)['"]>/gi,
    css: /<link.*href=['"](.+)['"]/gi
  },
  replace: {
    js: '<script src="{{filePath}}"></script>', // <-- Change this line
    css: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{filePath}}" />'
  }
},
yml: {
  block: /(([\s\t]*)#\s*bower:*(\S*)\s*)(\n|\r|.)*?(#\s*endbower\s*)/gi,
  detect: {
    js: /-\s(.+)/gi,
    css: /-\s(.+)/gi
  },
  replace: {
    js: '- {{filePath}}'
    css: '- {{filePath}}'
  }
}
```

Add this to your grunt config in this spot:

```
'bower-install': {
  ...
  fileTypes: ... above block ...
}
```

It is a little tricky but I hope that all makes sense.

Comment: As per the source (https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install/blob/master/tasks/bower-install.js#L80) it seems to just pass through any parameters you give it. Other than that I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

@sharpper and other answers mentioning the `fileTypes` setting work, but you need a grunt-bower-install version that passes that setting on to wiredep. I had version 0.7.0 and it did not respect that setting. I upgraded using `npm install grunt-bower-install` to version 1.3.0 and then the setting started to work.